# How to print a warning every set number of times (Java)

Tags: java

(If there is already a question asking this please just send me the link in the comments. I did not find anything)

I was doing a small app, like MasterMind (but way simpler and not like it) and I wanted to help the user if he tried for example 5 times and didn't succeed.

```
int counter = 1;
while (flag){
    System.out.println("Counter");
    int guess = input.nextInt();
    counter++;

    if (counter>=5 && ) {
        System.out.println("I'm helping");
    }
}
```

`if (counter>=5 && )` How do I tell it to help the user every 3 attempts how the fifth? Thanks

Comment: can you post a test case.
say user attempted 5 times...when do we alert him ?
on his 6th attempt or on his 8th attempt (3rd attempt after first 5 attempts)

Comment: I would be the fifth, the eight, etc. so after 5, it would be 5+3x

Comment: if (counter >= 5 && (counter - 5) % 3 == 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every three attempts after the fifth, including the fifth?

```
if (counter >= 5 && (counter - 5) % 3 == 0 ) {
```

So say it was the 8th time, the if statement would be true because `8 - 5 = 3` and `3 % 3 == 0`

If it was the 11th time, it would also be true because `11 - 5 = 6` and `6 % 3 == 0`

The mod function (`%`) returns the remainder of the first number divided by the second number. If the remainder is 0, then the first number is divisible by the second.

For example: `8 % 3` is `2` because `3` goes into `8` twice, with a remainder of `2`.

And `9 % 3` is `0` because `3` goes into `9` three times evenly.

---

Edit:

The reason I had to change add the condition that `counter >= 5` for the second part is because if the counter was `2` and you subtract `5` from that, you get `-3`. Then, `-3 % 3` will be `0` and the condition would be true, but that's not what you want. It has to be greater than or equal to 5, and every third number after 5 (inclusive).

Comment: counter == 5 just became unnecessary

Comment: @KshitijMehta No because he wants it to help on the fifth one as well (I think).

Comment: He does, but your second clause will handle that for you. After your fix your other bug, that is... counter - 5 % 3 is counter - (5 % 3), not (counter - 5) % 3. Use brackets to avoid bugs like these.

Comment: It doesn't work... but this one did: if (counter > 5 && (6-counter) % 3 == 0) Just like I wanted. I'm not sure why I have to place the 6 instead of 5, but it helps on the fifth attempt, eight, etc. Thanks for the time! Got it now

Comment: @KshitijMehta Thank you for the corrections (with the brackets). And yes, I didn't think that it would be `0 % 3` which would be 0.

Comment: @EnderEgg Yeah sorry about that. It's fixed now.